# Distinct pairs with equal sum mod p

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and $\mathbb{F}$ be a field with $p$ elements. Define the sets

$$A=\{ (m_1,m_2) : m_1, m_2 \in \mathbb{F}, m_1 \neq m_2 \}$$

and

$$T =\{ (a_{1},a_{2}) : a_1, a_2 \in A, a_1 \neq a_2 \}.$$

Where $a_1 \neq a_2$ means that either the first or second elements of the tuple are not equal.

How many elements are in $T$?

Let $f(a)=f((m_1,m_2))=m_1+m_2$

$$T_2 =\{ (a_{1},a_{2}) : a_1, a_2 \in A, f(a_1)=f(a_2), a_1 \neq a_2 \}.$$

How many elements are in $T_2$?

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?  I suspect you're missing some conditions on $T$.  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: The title refers to my question about $T_2$.

Comment: Sorry, I must have been seeing an outdated copy of the page, how odd!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $p=2$ it's easy to verify that $|A| = |T_2| = 2$.  When $p$ is odd, verify that for each $q \in \mathbb F_p$, the set $S_q = \{a \in A: f(a) = q\}$ has size exactly $p-1$ (hint: when $p$ is odd, every element of $\mathbb F_p$ is divisible by $2$).

Now try to understand why $|T_2| = \sum_{q \in \mathbb F_p} |S_q|\cdot(|S_q| - 1)$ (it helps if you've already thought about Rebecca's answer).

Answer (score 2):

If $S$ in any finite set then the set $\{(x,y) \in S \times S:x \neq y\}$ has size $|S| \times (|S|-1)$.

Consequently,
\begin{align*}
|T| &= |A| \times (|A|-1) \\
    &= p(p-1) \times (p(p-1)-1) \\
    &= p^4-2p^3+p.
\end{align*}